# Draw polygon on map using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps, spring-boot

I want to display a map inside my view. I’m using `angularjs` and s`pring boot` in my project. I have to let the user draw a polygon in order to save the coordinate of this polygon, and then let him edit it or delete it from the map (after the save of course). I searched about those things and I found that I can use `ngmap`. But in the examples that I have found I can't find the way of the draw. What I want to do is similar to this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/188/).

Can anyone guide me please?